# Which magical creatures would you choose for your army?

Tags: magic, warfare

Ok this hypothetical scenario. 
Years ago a portal opened on Earth to a dying dimension. Several magical creatures fleeing their dying world crossed over into ours. In response several secret societies of supernatural creatures already living among us chose to reveal themselves. The public response by rounding up these creatures and putting them into the camps. In order to prevent a war the supernatural creatures banded together to create a small pocket dimension( roughly half the size of the US) whith it's entrance into our world the Canadian wilderness. Once most of that supernatural creatures crossed over so there  was peace for a time. But the entrance to the pocket dimension was found and now they must prepare themselves for an attack.

1.your enemy is roughly as advanced as we are today.

You have very few if any weapons.

Which 7 creatures would be most useful in a conflict like this? Why?

Of the 7 what would be the ratio for the creatures in the army? ( example 1 vampire for every 1500 werewolves)

1 vampires powers: enhance strength enhance speed. Abilty to teleportty to through shadows.  Turn into a swarm of bats. Regeneration and immortality.
Weaknesses: sunlight, homes that have not been invited into, holy objects ( if wielded by a true believer), decapitation, wooden stakes to the heart.

Werewolfs: powers: enhance strength regeneration the ability to turn into wolf human hybrid. 
Weaknesses: silver, and the you lose all power on a new moon ( but full moon booster power)

Fea: powers: can control plants and animals, telekinesis and control the weather. Heal others can make illusions. Can turn into animals.
Weaknesses: iron

Dragons: powers: very large ( about the size smog is in The Hobbit), very strong and can breathe fire hot enough to melt rock and steel. Nearly invulnerable scales and bones. I can fly.

Weaknesses: require a large food supply.

Titans. Powers extremely large ( 50 to 70 feet high.) Near invulnerable bones and muscles, incredibly strong.

Fire elementals powers : may the pure fire. Can change shape. Can fly

Weaknesses: the counter element (water) or A vacuum

Water elemental: made of water can change shape.
Weaknesses: counter element (fire) or just intense heat.

Jins powers: ability to turn to smoke. Ability to shapeshift telekinesis, pyrokinesis. The ability to change something into a new element ( turning rock into gold or flesh and stone for example)

Sirens: can control people with their voice. Can breathe underwater can turn into human fish hybrid.
Weaknesses: must be able to hear them to be controlled by them.

Ghosts: powers: can pass through any solid object. Can turn invisible. Can control people's emotions. ( making them experience intense grief guilt or fear)
Weaknesses: they are intangible and unable to physically harm anyone.

Unicorns: powers: flight and teleportation

Skinwalkers: the ability to change to any human or animal.

Weaknesses: cannot turn into something larger than 5 times their body mass. Cannot turn to something smaller in 5th of their body mass.

Half angels: enhance strength, enhance speed.

Sea serpent very large very strong can breathe underwater tough enough to withstand the water pressure at the bottom of the ocean.

Golumns: made of clay and strength regeneration

Gargoyles: can fly have skin as tough as stone.

Comment: Any answer to this is going to primarily be opinion based.  Try to redo the question to make the answer more objective.  You should also discuss your evaluation criteria.

Comment: While your naming of creatures available is useful, you forget about the most important parts (of any war, I think): why and where?
 If you are sitting in a own universe and trying to mess with a modern day world because you feel like the biggest being in universe, you will soon meet something that would be able to melt even your dragon, even if its looking just like a barrel on a parachute.

Comment: @Confused Merlin. Let me fix that second.

Comment: @Confused Merlin is this any better?

Comment: Interesting premise, but this question is far too open-ended.  You are practically asking us to create the whole story.

Comment: @dan111 can you at least tell me which 7 creatures be most useful in the war and why?

Comment: @BryanMcClure There are so many options with all of the powerful creatures you propose.  Which you choose would be based on what you want the plot to be like.

Comment: you could watch Narnia or LotR, that'll give you plenty of Ideas (even Harry Potter will give you some ideas)

Answer (score 1):

Looking over that list, I think we still need more specific task. At the moment that does feel less like world-building but plotting advice.

Anyway, all that does look like a human is useful if you enemy is human after all. Try to hide a commando-dragon at the *other side* (I'll use this therm to describe our world). Neverless, that sounds like the party-building part of some sort of game, if yo ask me.

But still... they expecting an attack. Why? I mean, they do have their pocket-dimension where they do dwell and don#t cause any harm to the other side. Are there some rouge specimen, that do enjoy causing trouble in canadian small settlements for nothing else but fun? Or do they have something in their pocket-dimension, that *someone* (a three-letter-agency from a three-letter-country for example) might be interested in? Some rare ore from that dimension of theirs? They could trade. Or do these bad guys just want their bodies for medical tests?

Yes, right now it feels way to open, your question. All of the guys you named would be useful in a certain task. For example a sea serpent is something I would expect to be very good at denying access to a lake. Some of them could close a small passage in the ocean, like... that one in the red sea, or this one next to Indonesia. There are no battleships ready to combat any more at this earth of ours, and these stealthy ships of ours do have a paper-thin hull. Even more, a submarine would be a suicide-mission. At the other side, your serpent would be pretty hard to spot (not magnetic, no "engine", but a SAD could work maybe, or they sonar-ping him ear-dumb). All they could do is send chopper and drop explosives into the water, because any ships rudder would be a prime target for a serpent who know what to do. The only surface-vessel that would be pretty invulnable to these bad fishies were last to be seen at our surface waters during world war 2. And... wait, maybe the Kirov would work, if you use it to deploy something else than missiles with it.

As you see... provide the scenario fleshed out, and we can estimate things to think of you might forget to take into account. But just asking " I have a dozen magical creatures I want to fight a modern day army... tell me what happen!" is... well, an answer fitting this question of yours would probably make its way into the book-stores.

Answer (score 0):

Since your enemy is a modern military, you will want to strike quickly and bring the battle to them.  If they get through the portal and onto your land, many of your warriors advantages will be lost.

Strategically, your best bet is infiltration and assasination.  Form your Jins and Skinwalkers as terrorist cells within your enemy's support lines.  Each cell should also have at least a couple ghosts for information gathering and a siren for interrogation.

To distract your enemy, stage a large force at the portal; a hundred titans riding dragons with fire elementals for air support, should hold their attention.  Add a legion of regenerating golums up front as cannon fodder.

The goal of these front-line troops is simple.  Hold the doorway, while your terrorist cells do their jobs.  While the enemy is on his own soil, he'll be over-confident, and therefore more vulnerable to infiltration.  Once they are in your mystical realm, they'll be frightened and paranoid (rightfully so!).  Under those conditions, your agents in their supply lines won't be able to get close.

The final piece of the puzzle is a platoon of Fleas to bring in some really miserable weather.  If it is winter, a blizzard would be great.  If not, rain will do.  Horrible weather to hide the powerful full moon.

Now, with the enemy forces distracted and miserable, activate your terror cells...

- assasinate the officers
- poison the troop rations
- booby-trap the latrines
- have the ghosts spread fear among the troops

Then Cry Havoc and Let Loose the Dogs of War!!!!
by sending in the werewolves!

Comment: It said you could only have 7 creatures, you used 9. I suggest scrap the feas and sirens as ghosts can interrogate by causing fear.